# missing android package in nativescript using typescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I get the following error message:

```
main-page.ts(15,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'android'.
```

After creating a new nativescript project using typescript.

```
tns create demo --template typescript
```

And adding the following xml, ts files.

main-page.xml

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
  <StackLayout>
    <Placeholder creatingView="creatingView"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
import placeholder = require("ui/placeholder");

export function creatingView(args: placeholder.CreateViewEventData) {
    var nativeView = new android.widget.CalendarView(args.context);
    args.view = nativeView;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a TypeScript compiler warning, it's not an error per se. You can install the platform definitions into your Nativescript project if you want to prevent these warnings: `npm i tns-platform-declarations`

You could still run the `TSC` to transpile the TypeScript into Javascript and it work. It's just for type checking warning which is the benefit of TypeScript :)

Hope all of this makes sense and helps out.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations

Comment: Thanks, @BradMartin, after installing  tns-platform-declarations package and adding the following snippet to tsconfig.json

    "files": [
        "/node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android17.d.ts"
    ] 

the compiler found the android package.

Comment: Do you mind accepting the answer so this question can be resolved on the SO threads?

Comment: I was struggling for so long with this. For anyone else - if you are working with typescript and your compilation fails, because it cannot find some classes/functions (like `android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`), wrap it as any - `(android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat as any).checkSelfPermission`

Comment: Even simpler is to `declare var android: any` so then no need to cast as any each time you use the android namespace.